# New to C programming, need guidance

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I have an assignment where I must calculate the load on a cantilever beam at 1 ft increments until it reaches 2% of the beam length. My calculations work, and the first portion of the for loop seems to do what it is designed to do. I just can't figure out how to increment the distance to the load from the fixed point end of the cantilever beam. I tried to use a while loop, and then a couple of if statements. I just don't understand enough at this point to make it work.

Here is the text of the assignment:
"Write a C program to read the information for each beam from the beam.txt data file (one point at a time) and print a report, both to the screen and to an output file (deflection.txt) that places the applied load at 1-foot intervals starting at one foot from the fixed end (i.e., at 1 foot) and moving down the length of the beam. Once this is working, modify the program so that the deflections for each beam are printed only as long as they are less than 2% of the beam length. When the beam deflection is greater than or equal to 2%, the program should stop computing values for that beam and go on to the next. If the deflection distance of 2% is never reached, the program should print an appropriate message."

Here is what the output should look like:

```
********************************************
             BEAM DEFLECTION                 

BEAM NO. X   Total length = xx.xx ft
             2% of length = xx.xx ft

   DISTANCE FROM FIXED END       DEFLECTION
            1.00                       xxx.xx
            2.00                   xxx.xx
             .                        .
             .                        .
             .                        .

BEAM NO. X   Total length = xx.xx ft
             2% of length = xx.xx ft

   DISTANCE FROM FIXED END       DEFLECTION
            1.00                   xxx.xx
            2.00                   xxx.xx
             .                        .
             .                        .
             .                        .
     Deflection of 2% of length not reached
********************************************
```

My output either has nothing below each beam section, or the incrementation is off, like under beam 1 it is 1.00 2.00, under beam 2 it is 2.00 3.00, and so on.

This is my unsuccessful code:

```
/* Preprocessor directives */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define infile "C:\\Users\\tommc\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ENGR 200\\beam.txt"
#define outfile "C:\\Users\\tommc\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ENGR 200\\deflection.txt"

/* Main function */
int main(void)
{
   /* Declare variables */
   double load, load_len=1, elast, inert, beam_len, beam_base, deflection, perc_len;
   int i, ndata;
   FILE *beam=NULL, *deflect=NULL;
   
   /* open files */
   
   beam=fopen(infile, "r");
   deflect=fopen(outfile, "w");
   
   /* Print headings */
   
   printf("********************************************");
   printf("\n             BEAM DEFLECTION");
   fprintf(deflect,"********************************************");
   fprintf(deflect,"\n             BEAM DEFLECTION");
   
   /* Verify input file */
   
   if(beam==NULL)
   {
    printf("\n\n\n\n ERROR OPENING INPUT FILE.");
    printf("\n\n PROGRAM TERMINATED.\n\n\n");
    return 1;
   }
   
   /* Read control number */
   
   fscanf(beam, "%i", &ndata);

   /* Compute beam deflection and print results */
   
   for(i=1; i<=ndata; i++)
   {
   /* read in data */
    fscanf(beam, "%lf %lf %lf %lf", &beam_len, &beam_base, &elast, &load);
    inert=(beam_base*pow(beam_len,3.0))/12.0;
    deflection=(load*pow(load_len,2.0))/(2.0*elast*inert)*(beam_len-(load_len/3.0));
    perc_len=(0.02*beam_len);
    printf("\nBEAM NO %d   Total length = %5.2lf ft", i, beam_len);
    printf("\n            2%% of length = %5.2lf ft", perc_len);
    printf("\n   DISTANCE FROM FIXED END      DEFLECTION ");
    printf("\n            %4.2lf                  %6.2lf", load_len, deflection);
    fprintf(deflect, "\nBEAM NO %d   Total length = %5.2lf ft", i, beam_len);
    fprintf(deflect, "\n            2%% of length = %5.2lf ft", beam_len*0.02);
    fprintf(deflect, "\n   DISTANCE FROM FIXED END      DEFLECTION ");
    load_len++;
   if(deflection < perc_len)
   {
    printf("\n            %4.2lf                  %6.2lf", load_len, deflection);
   }
   
   if(deflection>=perc_len)
   {
    printf("\nDeflection of 2%% of length not reached");
   }
   }
       
   printf("\n********************************************\n\n\n");
   fprintf(deflect,"\n********************************************\n\n\n");
   
   /* Close the files */
   
   fclose(beam);
   fclose(deflect);
   
   /* Exit the program */
   return 0;
}
/******************************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> DISTANCE FROM FIXED END DEFLECTION 1.00 xxx.xx 2.00 xxx.xx . . . . . . Deflection of 2% of length not reached

Your problem is that you need to have a *nested* loop over `load_len` *for each beam*, and you are not doing that.

Your code should look like this:

```
for (beam_no = 0; beam_no < ndata; beam_no++) {  /* 1 */
  /* read the data for this beam */
  for (load_len = 0; load_len < beam_len; load_len++) {
    /* print deflections here */
  }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Note that in `C` you should *always* start your loops from `0` and continue until `< ndata` -- that's idiomatic. Having loops which start at `1` and continue until `<= ndata` will bite you sooner or later.